# How to start a charity project making use of college students as cram school teachers for orphans in lower levels of education?

Tags: small-communities, finance, children

I want to start a charity project that makes use of the human capital we have here in Morocco. The targeted population of the project is orphans of the same city, and I'm having thoughts about making it national in three to four years time. The goal of the project is to help orphans get proper education and support from the students who are evidently teacher material. It's like a cram school that goes to orphanages to help the orphans, not the orphans going to cram school. And of course, it's a charity, so they won't pay for it.

For starters, I want to know how to study the reliability of the project in addition to its possibility of being applied in reality?

I want to know how to convince college students to volunteer for the project and how to get them committed to it?

How would I put together a workplan of the entire project?

How can I get sponsors to help with the project?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Could you split this out into distinct questions? Additionally, this site focuses on the community building aspect. We can help with those areas.